# How does one prepare---on TEXLIVE--- OpenType, Unicode based, fonts for use with Xe(La)Tex

Tags: xetex, texlive, unicode, opentype

I downloaded the Cree syllabics font pitabek from:

http://www.languagegeek.com/font/fontdownload.html

According to the information this font is opentype and follows the Unicode coding for Cree syllabics

I unzipped the file and obtained   `pitabek.ttf`. I put this file in:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/PITABEK
```

Then I ran  ttf2afm -o pitabek.afm  to obtain  pitabek.afm . I placed this file in:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/fonts/afm/public/PITABEK
```

Then I ran ttf2tfm to obtain  pitabek.tfm . I placed this file in:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/fonts/tfm/public/PITABEK
```

I then ran updatedb
I then ran texconfig
I then created the following file:

```
% [pitabek_01_2015.0518.tex]

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{pitabek}            

\def\e{^^^^1401}

\def\i{^^^^1403}
.....

\begin{document}

\e \i  
....

\end{document}
```

I then ran (from the command line)

```
xelatex pitabek_01_2015.0518.tex
```

I received the following error message:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"

! The font "pitabek/B/B" cannot be found.
```

My question is:

How do I prepare the font  pitabek , so that xelatex can find it?

Comment: Why would you convert the `.ttf` font to TeX font formats? All you need to do is to install the `.ttf` font on your system as you would install any other font. `xelatex` is able to load any of your system fonts.

Comment: delete the tfm you made, that will just confuse tex, and install the font into your fontconfig font path (or just leave it in the same directory as your file) xetex does not need tfm for system fonts.